# Numpy.arrange with datetime - ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed:

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, numpy

I am building a date axis for a matplotlib chart that should have a tick every 7 days. I am using numpy to build the range and the interval but am receiving the error message `ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed` I've isolated the code to the important elements

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
first_date = datetime.datetime( 2014, 12, 13)
last_date = datetime.datetime( 2015, 1, 1)

print np.arange(first_date, last_date,7)
```

Expected Output:

```
[datetime.datetime( 2014, 12, 13) datetime.datetime( 2014, 12, 20) datetime.datetime( 2014, 12, 27)]
```

Comment: Have you tried `np.datetime64('2014-12-13')` instead of `datetime.datetime`?

Comment: I get a `MemoryError` instead, also for @PauloScardine's proposed solution.

Comment: @PauloScardine thanks, this did work and I posted it as a solution, but still wonder why the OP doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, that error disappeared...

Answer (score 2):

With the suggestion of np.datetime64 from Paulo Scardine, I was able to successfully solve this. I am posting a solution that others might find useful:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
first_date = np.datetime64('2014-12-13')
last_date = np.datetime64('2015-01-01')

print np.arange(first_date, last_date,7)
```

Comment: Glad to help - BTW `import datetime` is unnecessary now... :-)

Answer (score 1):

NumPy has his own optimized version of `datetime.datetime`: `numpy.datetime64`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(np.datetime64('2014-12-13'), np.datetime64('2015-01-01'), 7)
array(['2014-12-13', '2014-12-20', '2014-12-27'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```